# Convert from one date format to another in PHP

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
echo $startdate1 = $_POST['registration_opens_date'];
echo $enddate1   = $_POST['registration_ends_date'];
```

How to convert date format from `January 1, 2014 11:15 PM` to `2014-01-01 23:15:00`.

Comment: `echo date_create('January 1, 2014 11:15 PM')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['registration_opens_date']));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['registration_ends_date']));
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `H` is the 24-hour format, and `h` is the 12-hour format. The OP seems to want the former.

Comment: This would not work on 32 bit systems after 2038 or before 1970

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo date_format(date_create($startdate1), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here  is an exemple  of what  you  want

```
<?php
 echo $test="January 1, 2014 11:15";
 $test= date_create($test);
 echo "<br>";
 echo date_format($test,'Y-m-d h:i:s'); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. In case you missed it, a very similar solution has already been suggested, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21406749/1438393).