# Date format need to be converted

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

My date format is in m-d-y.  Now i want to convert it in y-m-d format in php

```
<input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium default-date-picker"   size="16" type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" value="" />
```

PHP

```
$from_datenew = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['from_date']));
```

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406665/convert-from-one-date-format-to-another-in-php/21406743#21406743

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
$originalDate = $_POST['from_date'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: In one line `$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['from_date']));`

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the OP's trial?

Comment: @Jenz : i tried but its not working

Comment: what is the output of $_POST['from_date']? Is it a string?

Comment: @Jenz sorry for the delay answer. I got output as $_POST['from_date'] = 01-29-2014

Comment: what is the output of strtotime($_POST['from_date']).. actually this should work fine.

Comment: it gives me a empty value

Comment: then itz the problem with your code/value..not in the method..

Comment: i dont no what exactly is the problem. But I have found the solution using function explode.

Answer (score 0):

```
$from_datenew = date_format(
    date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $_POST['from_date']),
    'Y-m-d'
);
```

Comment: Edakos I tried but not working

Comment: I see. Fixed now the original format, from 'm-d-y' (12-31-13) to 'm-d-Y' (12-31-2013). Please try now.